# Правка CONSTRAINT'ов одним скриптом

Tags: sql, oracle

Хотелось бы что-нибудь вроде:

```
UPDATE USER_CONSTRAINTS
  SET SEARCH_CONDITION_VC = '(CUR_CUR_ID = 128 AND XTYP_XTYP_ID = 0) OR (CUR_CUR_ID != 128 AND XTYP_XTYP_ID != 0)'
  WHERE SEARCH_CONDITION_VC = '(CUR_CUR_ID = 2 AND XTYP_XTYP_ID = 0) OR (CUR_CUR_ID != 2 AND XTYP_XTYP_ID != 0)';
```

Но это представление, понятное дело, править нельзя. А как бы так можно было поправить массово все чеки?

Comment: Не надо изменять словарь данных напрямую - это очень опасно. Лучше динамически сгенерировать DDL скрипты и запустить их...

Comment: Ну, т.к. долго думать некогда - просто вытянул имена проверок и таблиц и в экселе быстренько сгенерировал drop и add команды, но чет как-то не круто.

Comment: А почему бы не сделать это SQL-ем вместо Excel'а?

Comment: В чем смысл править констрейнты одним скриптом? У вас десяток идентичных констрейнтов? Я бы тогда задумался о структуре БД для начала.

Comment: В чужой монастырь со своим уставом не ходят. В этой БД так, мне в неё нужно кое-что смигрировать нужно. Ну да ладно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, в принципе, в цикле обработать через `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```
begin
  for i in (select * from USER_CONSTRAINTS 
    where SEARCH_CONDITION_VC = '(CUR_CUR_ID = 2 AND XTYP_XTYP_ID = 0) OR (CUR_CUR_ID != 2 AND XTYP_XTYP_ID != 0)'
    ) loop
    execute immediate 'alter table ' || i.table_name || ' drop comstraint ' || i.constraint_name;
    execute immediate 'alter table ' || i.table_name || ' add comstraint ' || i.constraint_name ||
        ' check (CUR_CUR_ID = 128 AND XTYP_XTYP_ID = 0) OR (CUR_CUR_ID != 128 AND XTYP_XTYP_ID != 0)';
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Или сразу не запускать (на всякий пожарный), а сгенерировать строки и вывести их через `dbms_output`, потом пробежать глазами и убедиться, что все правильно. И не стоит забывать, что DDL транзакции нельзя откатить, как DML.